# Optimizing a Tensorflow Data Pipeline With Mixed Datatypes

Tags: python, tensorflow

### Edit:

Since I was asked for code. Here's my model:

```
def def_model():
  image_input = Input(shape=(200,200,3), name="image") 
  feature_input = Input(shape=(500,5), name="time")
  output = decoder(feature_input,image_input,10,10)
  model = Model(
      inputs=[image_input, feature_input],
      outputs=output,
    )
  opt_adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(clipnorm=0.5, epsilon=0.1)
  model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=opt_adam)
  return(model)
```

My current training loops contain a version of the following data inputs:

```
img_batch = tf.stack(image_list,axis=0)
inputs_batch = tf.reshape(tf.stack([inputs]*8,axis=0),[8,500,5])
outputs_batch = tf.reshape(tf.stack([outputs]*8,axis=0),[8,500,1])
model.fit({"image": img_batch, "time_features": inputs_batch},
          outputs_batch,
          epochs=3,
          batch_size = 1,
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback]
          )
```

I checked using Tensorboard, and the loop itself is probably the least efficient part of the training (the gap between each call to fit is larger than the amount of time it spends training).

---

### Original Question

I am training a model with mixed datatypes, and it is quite slowly. So, I am trying to speed it up. Usually, I would attempt to do this by turning my data into one tensor. However, that is probably not an option this time around. I have two inputs, a time series and an image, and I have a time series output.

The time series' have shape (length_of_sequence,5) and (length_of_sequence,1), and both are floats. The image is a square (n,n) image with integer values. I guess in principle I could turn these into two separate tensors, but what are my best options in creating a data pipeline?

Comment: Can you show your code and dummy data

Comment: `image_list` is a list of `200x200x3` images?

Comment: @AloneTogether yeah, eight of them (belonging to the same time series) to be trained in parallel.

Comment: @AloneTogether I am training this on Colab, and again, as I wrote in the edit of my question, I have checked how well resources are being used using Tensorboard. The biggest problem is the loop itself. My original hope was to use tf.data in a way that is compatible with multiple datatypes.

Comment: Ok, by loop, you mean the training loop right? Can you share your notebook?

Comment: @AloneTogether No, I cannot share the actual code. I'll lose my job and probably be fined or jailed (this project is for a part of the public sector). However, if there is no super-efficient way a la tf.data tensors to optimize my training, I guess I'll have to think outside the box a bit.
Yeah, loop is the training loop; It's looping over the dataset.

Comment: You could probably optimize a bit by not loading your whole dataset into memory

Comment: @AloneTogether Alright, thanks, I'll try it

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `tfrecord` is what u need.

- [tf.data.TFRecordDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset)
- [Better performance with the tf.data API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance)

Answer (score 1):

If your ramp-up for a fit is long, this points to a memory I/O issue.

> (the gap between each call to fit is larger than the amount of time it
> spends training)

From a performance perspective, it seems weird that you access 2 different variables alternatingly in a loop. As a "preconditioning" step, can you combine the data from `img_batch` and `inputs_batch` into 1 auxiliary variable (with adjusted shape) before fitting? How does your runtime performance look like when only accessing this 1 variable in your loop?

Comment: If I could've, I would have a long time ago, since that would essentially allow me to use a tf.data tensor, but for this project it's not really much of an option; I have to be able to test them both separately in the model and together, so that I can test multiple architectures.